# Canonical isomorphisms and HoTT

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

The univalence axiom in homotopy type theory states that isomorphism is equality.

However, many issues in in formalizing pure math arise from the fact that humans are good at (unconsciously) identifying things that are *canonically* isomorphic while machines are not. For an interesting discussion see a blog [post](https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/equality-part-3-canonical-isomorphism/) by Prof. Buzzard.

Is there a middle ground between dependent type theory and HoTT where only canonically isomorphic things are considered equal? Is there any work in that direction?

In particular, that would require a robust formal definition of canonical isomorphisms.

Comment: The univalence axiom is stated a bit imprecisely. It states that a certain map is an equivalence, and is best paraphrased as "equality of types is equivalent to equivalence of types". But yes, people think about the problem, I know some :-)

Comment: My opinion is that "canonical isomorphism" is not a _mathematical_ concept but a cultural/societal one.  In particular, it is intensional and context-dependent, and cannot be defined formally as a property of a particular isomorphism between particular objects in isolation.  The closest I can think of to formalizing it is to say that a canonical isomorphism is one that's been declared as an implicit coercion.

Comment: Hott does not consider canonical isomorphisms only at all. The idea is that equality $x=y$ is what allows you to replace $x$ by $y$ in any proposition without changing the truth value. Univalence says internally that propositions(=dependent types) $P$ formulated following the rules of dependent type theory see equivalence as an equality in the sense that, if $x\cong y$, one has $P(x)\cong P(y)$, coherently: univalence just says that a dependent type $P$ may be rectified as a kind of functor, thus sending equivalences of types $x\cong y$ to equivalent propositions(=types) $P(x)\cong P(y)$.

Comment: You may compare this to straightening/unstraightening in (higher)category theory.